# How to get clicks on disabled buttons with wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a disabled button, and it does not receive clicks when I use `EVT_BUTTON` on it. Is there a way to receive clicks even when it has been `Disabled()`?

Comment: Its nice to see the button in the disabled state. I am trying to achieve something like in a paint toolbar, where users click the tool and then can unselect that tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of disabling a button is so that the EVT_BUTTON event is not fired. I'm sure you could create create an ugly hack using EVT_LEFT_DOWN and detecting where the mouse is in your app as a workaround, but why bother? This is intended behavior.

Comment: Its nice to see the button in the disabled state. I am trying to achieve something like in a paint toolbar, where users click the tool and then can unselect that tool

Comment: Maybe what you want is a ToggleButton?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps wxpython has a mechanism similar to pygtk.

In pygtk you create a input-only (that is transparent) window over the widget you want to get clicks for and get your clicks there.